# Trying to install extension through Connect Manager getting depends on PHP extensions error

Tags: magento-1.9, php, extensions, soap, magento-connect

**I am trying to install Magento extension StitchLabs_ChannelIntegration but I am getting this error:**

> CONNECT ERROR: Package community/StitchLabs_ChannelIntegration 1.0.8 depends on PHP extensions: Array

**My specs:**

- Magento 1.9.?
- New Amazon EC2
- Latest httpd and php55w
- `php -m` shows:

  > [PHP Modules]
  >   bz2
  >   calendar
  >   Core
  >   ctype
  >   curl
  >   date
  >   dom
  >   ereg
  >   exif
  >   fileinfo
  >   filter
  >   ftp
  >   gd
  >   gettext
  >   gmp
  >   hash
  >   iconv
  >   json
  >   libxml
  >   mbstring
  >   mcrypt
  >   mhash
  >   mysql
  >   mysqli
  >   openssl
  >   pcntl
  >   pcre
  >   PDO
  >   pdo_mysql
  >   pdo_sqlite
  >   Phar
  >   readline
  >   Reflection
  >   session
  >   shmop
  >   SimpleXML
  >   sockets
  >   SPL
  >   sqlite3
  >   standard
  >   tokenizer
  >   wddx
  >   xml
  >   xmlreader
  >   xmlwriter
  >   xsl
  >   Zend OPcache
  >   zip
  >   zlib
  >   
  >   [Zend Modules]
  >   Zend OPcache

The only traction that I have made is that I have read that I need to add `extension=php_xsl.so` in `php.ini` but I don't have that installed cannot find anywhere to install this extension, only the dll version for windows.

trying to `yum install php-xsl` outputs:

> Loaded plugins: update-motd, upgrade-helper
>   Package php55w-xml-5.5.26-1.w6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
>   Nothing to do

and searching for `find / -name php_xsl.so` outputs nothing

***Please help***

Answer (score 2):

If I check the [`package.xml` of the extension](http://ext.topmage.com/extensions/44/28/StitchLabs_ChannelIntegration/) (version 1.0.8), then I see the following dependencies specified:

```
<dependencies>
  <required>
    <php>
      <min>5.1.0</min>
      <max>6.0.0</max>
    </php>
    <package>
      <name>Mage_Core_Modules</name>
      <channel>community</channel>
      <min>1.7.0.2</min>
      <max/>
    </package>
    <extension>
      <name>soap</name>
      <min/>
      <max/>
    </extension>
  </required>
</dependencies>
```

It depends on:

- PHP version >= 5.1.0 < 6.0.0
- package Mage_Core_Modules >= 1.7.0.2
- ## extension: soap

When I see the list of installed PHP extensions, I believe I don't see SOAP in there (!)...

You can install it using:

```
yum install php-soap
```

Then add this line to your `php.ini`:

```
extension='/usr/lib/php/modules/soap.so'
```

If you need more help on installing PHP SOAP, I'd advise you to just [Google it](https://www.google.nl/#q=yum+install+SOAP+PHP) and you'll find what you need...

Comment: Thanks, although I tried that of course I googled for solutions for hours. Why would I post on a forum for help if it was on google? Anyway, I just switched over to Ubuntu and now I am not having any problems. Thanks

Comment: @GaryFrey, the error says "depends on PHP extensions: Array" and the XML says "depends on SOAP" so that's what I found out. Your question did not provide any information on your attempts to install SOAP. Please add this to your question an provide what his happening after that (did php-soap install properly? can you install the module now? what errors do you get now?)