# Package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.2.2 depends on PHP extensions: Array

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-connect-manager

Upgraded magento 1.8 to 1.9.2.2 and having this error:

> Package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.2.2 depends on PHP extensions: Array

Anyone could know how solve this ? What Exactly need to be done? Also I'm installing the upgrade on root httpdoc/ is it the correct root?

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Comment: I am also getting same error after Magento Connect wizard but i am upgrading from 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.2.2. Error is `"CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.2.2 depends on PHP extensions: Array"`. I tried upgarding another website but it went well but this site got stock.

Comment: Enable PHP mcrypt extension.
It should fix it

Answer (score 2):

I've just checked `var/package/Lib_Varien-1.9.2.2.xml` and it contains the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <required>
        <php>
            <min>5.2.0</min>
            <max>6.0.0</max>
        </php>
        <package>
            <name>Lib_ZF</name>
            <channel>community</channel>
            <min>1.12.10.2</min>
            <max>1.12.10.2</max>
        </package>
        <extension>
            <name>PDO</name>
            <min></min>
            <max></max>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <name>SPL</name>
            <min></min>
            <max></max>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <name>curl</name>
            <min></min>
            <max></max>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <name>SimpleXML</name>
            <min></min>
            <max></max>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <name>dom</name>
            <min></min>
            <max></max>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <name>gd</name>
            <min></min>
            <max></max>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <name>iconv</name>
            <min></min>
            <max></max>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <name>pdo_mysql</name>
            <min></min>
            <max></max>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <name>mcrypt</name>
            <min></min>
            <max></max>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <name>pcre</name>
            <min></min>
            <max></max>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <name>Reflection</name>
            <min></min>
            <max></max>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <name>session</name>
            <min></min>
            <max></max>
        </extension>
    </required>
</dependencies>
```

So you should check your server and Magento install to see if all of this is in place. If it isn't you have to solve this before `Lib_Varien-1.9.2.2.xml` can be installed.

More details on a similar issue can be found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/trying-to-install-extension-through-connect-manager-getting-depends-on-php-exten).